# How to invoke UnitOfWork where and firstordefault by using reflector?

Tags: vb.net, generic-programming, reflector, .net-reflector

I tried to invoke UnitOfWork where and firstordefault by using reflector?

Normal command

```
Me.UnitOfWork.GetAll(Of RG.Model.Student).Where(Function(x) x.Id = 1).FirstOrDefault
```

But i tried to change by using reflector. This is my current code

```
Dim typeModel = Type.GetType("RG.Model.Student, RG.Model")
Dim method = Me.UnitOfWork.GetType().GetMethod("GetAll")
Dim generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeModel)
Dim retVal As Object = generic.Invoke(Me.UnitOfWork, Nothing)
```

How to call Where? because I tried to call getMethod after invoke, it will return Nothing.

Comment: `Where` is an extension function defined in System.Linq.Enumerable. It's not actually a member of retVal.

Comment: oic. that why i cant call where. any other way to call where?

Comment: You can call GetMethod on the class that implements Where (you'll need to pass static binding) but I think it's going to be a bit of a nightmare trying to create the filter function. Maybe let us know what exactly  you're attempting to achieve overall so that we can point another direction.